# Target text between href tags - CSS

Tags: css, class, href

I have 5 `<a>` tags with a class that puts a box with border around the word. I had to make the boxes very big and the text centers horizontally with `text-align: center` but not vertically.

I tried `vertical-align` to no success. How can I target the text to move into the middle of the box?

***HTML***

```
<a href="#" id="someid1" class="someclass">Small</a>
<a href="#" id="someid2" class="someclass">Medium</a>
<a href="#" id="someid3" class="someclass">Large</a>
```

etc etc

***CSS***

```css
#container a.someclass { border:1px #ACACAC solid;text-align:center; }
```

Comment: We need to see the HTML for the enclosing container.

Comment: I suggest you experiment with line-height

Comment: Thank you line-height did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `line-height` parameter rocks (if your menu items don't go multiline) - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xSde/)

```css
a.someclass {
    border: 1px #ACACAC solid;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px; /* the same as the height */
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is your box? You need to wrap each 'tag' inside a block element. Once it is inside a block element, you can use `vertical-align: middle;` to center it vertically. You additionally use absolute positions, or padding to vertically center it.

```
<div style="vertical-align: middle;">
<a href="#">text</a>
</div>
```

Also, the `id` parameter is unique. This means you can only use it once per page.

Comment: Oh yeah I know id's are unique...I just put that in for the example. I should have specified someid1, someid2. Are you saying that each "href" tag has to have a div around it that has display:block attached to it?

Comment: This is bad advice. You don't use `vertical-align` to vertically-align text, unless the container is `display:table-cell;`. Furthermore, you *don't* need absolute positioning for this.

Comment: @JezenThomas You're correct that I forgot to include `display: table-cell`.

Comment: Regardless, why not just follow convention and use `line-height`?

Comment: @JezenThomas [Convention](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) states that vertical alignment is accomplished using the `vertical-align` property.

Comment: That's vertical alignment of an element, not vertical alignment of text the element contains.

Comment: @JezenThomas Did you read `9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts`?

Comment: You're joking, right? You've linked me to a spec that explicitly says `vertical-align` vertically aligns *inline-blocks*, *i.e.*, boxes and *not* the text they contain, inside their respective line box.

Comment: The link was my mistake. Did you have a moment to read `9.4.2`?

Comment: Yes, njk, that's the section you told me to read. I read exactly that section and it shows in pretty clear language that you're a little confused about `vertical-align`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `line-height` to the same pixel value as the `height` of the container. No `padding` necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use ul and li tags and line-height and display: block

http://jsfiddle.net/DAKfK/